# Send coursework to individual students

Tags: google-classroom

The Google Classroom Share dialog offers the possibility of sharing course work with individual students. However, I can't seem to find anything in [the API reference](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/create) or [Python API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/classroom/v1/python/latest/classroom_v1.courses.courseWork.html) to do this programatically (i.e. there is no studentIds parameter anywhere).

Am I overlooking something, or is this (still) missing?

Comment: AFAIK, you can only create a coursework specific for a teacher but once a student is enrolled in a class, all classwork created for that class is automatically shared to all students. And as you've mentioned there is no `studentId` in the [courseWork resource](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework). Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, the feature is still missing. Like many other features.